# group first started date and last end date for records with a common field

Tags: sql-server

Here is an excerpt of my table data:

```
  |deviceid |    |failcount|        started         |           ended    |
  | a1078   |    |  2      |  2020-12-07 14:51:33   | 2020-12-07 17:30:16|
  |a1006    |    |  2      |  2020-12-09 15:58:01   | 2020-12-09 23:59:59|
  |a1006    |    |  2      |  2020-12-10 00:00:00   | 2020-12-10 16:40:02|
  |a136     |    |  71     |  2020-12-18 10:12:19   | 2020-12-18 23:59:59|
  |a136     |    |  71     |  2020-12-19 00:00:00   | 2020-12-19 04:27:23|
  |a1078    |    |  36     |  2020-12-21 10:07:09   | 2020-12-21 14:36:40|
```

What I am trying to get to is to get the earliest start date and the latest end date for each deviceid, BUT for only the same failcount number. The failcount number is the # of failures for each deviceid, so multiple deviceid's can have the same failcount number (should be very few).

This is what im trying to get to:

```
|deviceid|   |failcount|    |      started        |  |      ended        |
|a1078   |   |    2    |    | 2020-12-07 14:51:33 |  |2020-12-07 17:30:16|
|a1006   |   |    2    |    |2020-12-09 15:58:01  |  |2020-12-10 16:40:02|
|a136    |   |    71   |    |2020-12-18 10:12:19  |  |2020-12-19 04:27:23|
|a1078   |   |    36   |    | 2020-12-21 10:07:09 |  |2020-12-21 14:36:40|
```

I've tried variations of min/max but can't figure out how to keep different failcounts from same deviceid from being combined - for instance, in the above for deviceid a1078, I don't want the started for failcount 2 and the ended for failcount 36.

What I have so far is this but it is combining different failcounts for the same deviceid:

```
select deviceid
     , min(started) as started
     , max(started) as ended
from dayfail
where eventno = '600509'
and Convert(char(6),started, 112) = '202012'
group by deviceid
```

Thx in advance for any assistance to this sql newbie ;)

Comment: im sorry about the data formatting - i need to correct that

Comment: *"but it is combining different failcounts for the same deviceid:"* because `failcount` is neither in your `SELECT` nor `GROUP BY`. How are you expecting the statement to return `failcount` if it's not in the `SELECT`?

Comment: perhaps `select deviceID, failcount, ... group by deviceID, Failcount` .

Comment: Don't do `Convert(char(6),started, 112) = '202012'`, use proper date logic: `started >= '20201201' AND started < '20210101'`. The former is *not* SARGable, and would be far slower on a larger dataset.

Comment: im so sorry, I had the failcount in the select and it gave me the error that it wasn;t in the group by and somehow I just ignored that - i added it to group by and it works...geez...